# Need to over ride a !important from the index file

Tags: customization, color-picker

Something really weird happened. I want to change the color of this text but the index file has an !important there and when i change the color on my style.css file it doesn't work. What can i do to over ride that !important.

This is how it looks in my css file

```
h1.entry-title {
    color: #9A7B5C ;
}
```

i want that brown color but the index file isn't letting me change it from yellow. Please help and this how the index file looks like

```
DIV SECTION DIV.container NAV A, DIV DIV ARTICLE.post-860.page.type-page.status-publish.hentry HEADER.entry-header H1.entry-title, DIV DIV ARTICLE.post-860.page.type-page.status-publish.hentry DIV.entry-content P, DIV P STRONG EM A, DIV DIV ARTICLE.post-860.page.type-page.status-publish.hentry DIV.entry-content P.ui-draggable.ui-draggable-handle  {
    color: #ffe206 !important; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an id to your h1 and make your rule more specific, and with an important too. You can learn more about specificity [here](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/).

Comment: can you please show me how it would look like. please i am desperate

Comment: The HTML: `<h1 class="entry-title" id="your-id">A title</h1>`, the CSS: `h1#your-id.entry-title { color: red !important; }`

Comment: word press won't let me add the html part right

Comment: Of course it would, but that's a different question!

Answer (score 0):

This may break when you update your theme, you may need to look into a [child theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) to add the id, or change the on-page CSS.

Also, best practice is to not use on-page on inline CSS, for these reasons.